# Search contacts provider for phone numbers in multiple formats?

Tags: android

I've been working on a block of code to let the user search (character by character using an AutoCompleteTextView) contacts by name, email or phone number. I've worked out the below code:

```
// General contact data, so we have to get the DATA1 attribute and use MIMETYPE
                    // to figure out what it is. Usually we'd query, say, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI
                    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;
                    // Limit the query results to only the columns we need for faster operations.
                    // Using a projection also seems to make the query DISTINCT
                    String[] projection    = new String[] {ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                            ContactsContract.Data.DATA1,
                            ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE};
                    // Find contact records with an email address or phone number
                    // Search the name and data1 field (which may contain an email or phone number)
                    // for user-entered search phrase
                    String filter = "(" + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR " + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?)"
                            + " AND (" + ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + " LIKE ? OR " + ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?)";
                    String wildcardedConstraint = "%" + constraintString + "%";
                    String[] filterParams = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, wildcardedConstraint, wildcardedConstraint};
                    // Sort contacts with the most recently contacted ones first. That's often 0 (unset)
                    // so do a sub-sort by last updated date, most recent contacts first
                    String orderBy = ContactsContract.Contacts.LAST_TIME_CONTACTED + " DESC, " + ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTACT_LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP + " DESC";
                    Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, filter, filterParams, orderBy);
                    if (cursor != null) {
                        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME));
                            String data1 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DATA1));
                            String mimetype = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE));
                            String number = null;
                            String email = null;
                            if (mimetype.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                                email = data1;
                            } else if (mimetype.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {
                                number = data1;
                            }

                            items.add(new Person(name, number, email));

                            Log.e("temp", name + " " + data1 + " " + mimetype);
                        }

                        cursor.close();
                    }
```

There is a problem with the phone number search, however. In contacts, phone numbers are in many different formats:

- +101234567890
- (123) 456-7890
- 1234567890
- 123-456-7890

And so on.

How can I adapt my Contacts query filter so the user's input will find phone numbers in any format--preferably without making the entire query extremely slow?

Some solutions I've found rely on editing table data to standardize the phone numbers, which isn't an option with contacts. Maybe that normalized number field would work... if I could find a way to easily build it into this query on the Contacts Data table. I know I could do extra phone number searches for each record, or use Java to make the checks, but I think that would make it very slow. Perhaps a regexp SQL operator in the query--but I don't know how I could make it work for the user's character-by-character search where they may have only entered part of the phone number.

Any ideas?

Comment: NOT a duplicate. The other question is about how to do a basic search for phone number. The above code already successfully does a more advanced search by name, email address or phone number. The question asked is about how to search when the phone numbers in contacts are in multiple formats, which is not something the other question even considers.

Comment: That's what the `PhoneLookup` table is for; matching numbers that are in different formats. Notice where it mentions caller ID. If you don't want to use that, then filter your current dataset manually using `PhoneNumberUtils.compare()`.

Comment: Hang on. I just thought of another way you might be able to do this with your existing query. Lemme do some tests.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with Android's built-in SQLite function `PHONE_NUMBERS_EQUAL`, which compares two numbers and will return `1` if they're identical enough for caller ID purposes.

You simply need to change your `filter` as follows:

```
String filter = "(" + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=? OR "
    + ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?) AND "
    + "(PHONE_NUMBERS_EQUAL(" + ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + ", ?, 0) OR "
    + ContactsContract.Data.DATA1 + " LIKE ? OR "
    + ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?)";
```

And add another `wildcardedConstraint` to your `filterParams`:

```
String[] filterParams = new String[] { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                                       ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                                       wildcardedConstraint,
                                       wildcardedConstraint,
                                       wildcardedConstraint };
```

The final `INTEGER` parameter in the `PHONE_NUMBERS_EQUAL` function indicates whether to use strict number comparation; `1` meaning do use strict, `0` meaning non-strict. Apparently this is a system-wide setting that can be retrieved from the system `Resources`, but I am uncertain as to what factors dictate how this is determined for a particular environment. The example above just uses non-strict comparation. However, if it is a concern, the actual resource value can be obtained like so:

```
private static final String STRICT_COMPARE = "config_use_strict_phone_number_comparation";

...

int strictResId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(STRICT_COMPARE, "bool", "android");
boolean useStrict = Resources.getSystem().getBoolean(strictResId);
```

Comment: Oops. Hold on. I just realized I don't have the query correct. Gimme a minute to fix it.

Comment: OK, I think that's in keeping with what you were doing with the original.

Comment: Wow, what a cool function! I didn't know about that. I also appreciate the detailed code example!
But two problems: one, it doesn't actually seem to work? Two, I'm guessing it will only compare exact phone numbers--so it would fail when typing character by character, at least until the entire number is entered (in which case autocompletion would not be necessary)?

Comment: No sweat. Yeah, I came across that function when I was digging through the MMS/SMS Provider source a while back. I'd forgotten about it until I mentioned the `PhoneNumberUtils.compare()` method. Hope it works for ya. Cheers!

Comment: Well, it is a neat idea, but doesn't work for autocomplete.

Comment: Hmm, yeah, I just tested it with hard-coded `String`s. I'll see if I can get it working with autocomplete when I get some time a little later.

Comment: Well, I've got a query partially working with an `AutoCompleteTextView` at the moment. Had to go with more of a brute force method. The `PHONE_NUMBERS_EQUAL` can't be used for that, as you know, and I probably wouldn't've even mentioned it, had I thoroughly read your question and noticed that you were using an `AutoCompleteTextView`. Anyhoo, I've still got to track down why I'm getting a few false matches, but I should have something workable eventually.